# Trying to print entire array but only last one is printing into textview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an array of sentences from a webpage with WebKit and I'd like to print all of them on their own line into a textview. I think I have a loop to print the whole array, but its only printing the last sentence.

Here's what I have

```
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        // Receive message from Javascript, check & process message
        if message.name == "english", let englishLines = message.body as? [String] {
            // All of the sentences are printing in my console
            print(englishLines) 
            //Try Loop to print all of sentences on individual line
            for englishLine in englishLines {
                let eachEnglishLine = englishLine
                textView.text = eachEnglishLine
            }
        }
```

Only the last sentence prints in the textView.

Comment: Your first port of call should be the [Docs for `UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618623-text) and understand what the `text` property actually does.  From there it would have provided you with a better idea of the problem and sent you on a new journey to find a solution. Short answer is, `text` **sets** the text to be displayed, it does not append it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a much simpler way. Don't bother with the loop.

Replace your loop with:

```
textView.text = englishLines.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Your code doesn't work because you don't append each line. You simple assign each value to the text view so only the last line assigned will appear.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you’re setting the text to a totally new String on each iteration of the loop, rather than adding to it.

Instead try this:

```
textView.text += eachEnglishLine
```

If eachEnglishLine doesn’t already include a new line character, then you’ll need to add it yourself. In that case it would be:

```
textView.text += “\(eachEnglishLine)\n”
```